# Retrieve value inside Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I make a request to the server and get the response as observable. Inside the data, I have an ID which refers to another document, which I need to send another request to fetch the data and append it with the data of the parent Observable. How to achieve this?

With Promise, I can use async/await to do this, but I want to know how to achieve this using Observables

Sample with promise

```js
async func_name() {
  let data1 = await <first_server_call_returns_promise>();
  let data2 = await <second_call_with_data1.id_returns_promise>();
  data1.value = data2;
  return data1;
}
```

How to achieve the above with Observables?

**Edit 1**

Based on @TeddySterne reply the code I wrote is below but I'm getting an observable within the subscribe instead of actual data which prevent me to assign the observable to html

```
this.blogDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    exhaustMap((blogs) => {
        return blogs.map(blog => {
          const data = blog.payload.doc.data();
          const id = blog.payload.doc.id;
          return this.userService.getUserById(data.uid).pipe(
            map((user) => {
              const name = user.name;
              return { id, name, ...data}
            }),
          )
        })
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(finalData => {
    finalData.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  });
```

**Edit 2**

Below is the updated code that I have now

```
this.blogDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      exhaustMap((blogs: any[]) => {
        return zip(blogs.map((blog) => {
          const data = blog.payload.doc.data();
          const id = blog.payload.doc.id;
          console.log(data);
          return this.userService.getUserById(data.uid).pipe(
            map((value) => {
              console.log(value);
              return value;
            })
          )
        })).pipe(first())
      })
    ).subscribe(values => console.log("Values: ", values));
```

The
`console.log(data)` prints the data correctly but `console.log(value)` is not getting printed nor the `console.log("Values: ", values)`

When I use subscribe on `this.userService.getUserById(data.uid)`, it returns the expected single user document.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You can't, unless you convert them `.toPromise()`.

Comment: Its not necessary that I should use async/await. If there's any other possible way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `exhaustMap` to pipe the data to a second http call and then merge the data together when it returns.

#### Example

```js
import { zip } from 'rxjs/observable/zip';

this.http.get('/data1').pipe(
  exhaustMap((data1Arr: any[]) => {
    return zip(...data1Arr.map((data1) => {
      return this.http.get('/data2/' + data1.id).pipe(
        map((data2) => {
          data1.value = data2;
          return data1;
        }),
      );
    }).pipe(first());
  }),
).subscribe((fullQualifiedData) => {
  // do stuff with the data
});
```

#### [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vaywiw)

Comment: I tried the above code, but what I'm getting in fullQualifiedData is another observable, which I can't use directly on *ngFor in html file. Can you suggest any solution for this.

Comment: Use the async pipe to have it subscribe to your observable for you. `<div *ngFor="let data of dataObservable | async">{{data.id}}</div>`

Comment: I am using the snippet you mentioned but getting error as [object Object] cannot be used with ngfor. Should be an iterable or array

Comment: I didn't realize data1 was an array. I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried your solution. Tried to `console.log` inside the zip which works perfectly but inside the subscribe, it is not displaying anything when i `console.log` the `fullQualifiedData`. Any help on this?

Comment: Can you tell me what that ... dots do here? I know if I use that infront of an object will return the property of the object. But what will it do if we use it in front of an array?

Comment: It passes each argument to the function idividually `add(...[1, 2]) === add(1, 2)` [Read More about Spread here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Great. Thanks. Can you check this one too? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50349396/6712207. This is something that happens with the data1 where data1 has an array of ID

Answer (score 1):

> I tried the above code, but what I'm getting in fullQualifiedData is another observable, which I can't use directly on *ngFor in html file.

This is discussed in the Angular docs as well, but essentially you have two solutions:

## Using the `async` pipe

The `async` pipe will subscribe to the observable for you and then provide the data. This is easy to use, but note that every `async` pipe will create a new subscription, which in the case of HTTP requests can mean firing that request multiple times. So use with care.

```js
@Component({ … })
export class YourComponent {
  public data$ = this.http.getFoo();

  constructor(private http: Http) {}
}
```

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
    {{ data.foobar }}
</ng-container>
```

## Manually managing the subscription

```js
@Component({ … })
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  public data: Data;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.http.getFoo().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }
}
```

```
{{ data?.foobar }}
```

or

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data">
  {{ data.foobar }}
</ng-container>
```